# Read the phone number of device using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-os

I am developing an application for firefox os device. For some requirement I want to read the phone number of that device using javascript. Is there any api or method to read the phone number.

Comment: After setting the permissions in .manifest file, what is the javascript code I can use to retrieve phone number ? It is not mentioned in that answer.

Comment: The function is `navigator.getMobileIdAssertion()`, and it is available to certified and privileged applications.

Comment: I added this info to the other question, so this can remain closed.